# how to return an unknown value in c++

Tags: c++

```cpp
auto list::at(int index)
{
    for (auto node : VECTOR_OF_INT)
        if (node.getIndex() == index)
            return node.getValue();

    for (auto node : VECTOR_OF_DOUBLE)
        if (node.getIndex() == index)
            return node.getValue();

    for (auto node : VECTOR_OF_STRING)
        if (node.getIndex() == index)
            return node.getValue();
}
```

this is for my list class to find the index and i want to return a int, double or a string but i dont know how plz help.

Comment: Which C++ version are you using?

Comment: What exactly are those `VECTOR_OF_{INT,DOUBLE,STRING}`?

Comment: You are probably looking for `std::any`.

Comment: First, the function does not return a value in all cases. Hopefully a compile warning you'd see and address, otherwise it's undefined behavior. You could use [std::any](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) or [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).

Comment: @zdf std::any is very heavy. I would replace that with a comprehensive std::variant instead, which is cheap.

Comment: You should use a `std::any`/`std::variant` as elements of your list if you are trying to implement a heterogeneous list.

Comment: @Jellyboy Yes, if you are limited to a couple of known types.

Comment: Can you show us what you want the calling code to look like? Do you need it to be able test the type of the returned value? Or do you want to fall methods on it that work regardless of its type? Or something else entirely?

Comment: I do not have much information, but I guess this is a design problem. The only meaningful approach here would be to use templates. The return type of a function is fixed. ````auto```` will not help here, only, if you really use templates.

Comment: does `node` in your vector has the same type? why not return a `node`?

Comment: I suspect we are looking at a https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem So please take one logical step back and explain the problem you want to solve with the step you are asking about.

Answer (score 1):

See your question is not clear, but assuming you have three vectors of nodes of different types (int, float, std::string), and you want to return a value based on index. In that case you can use std::variant if you are using C++17 or above.

```
using MyVariant = std::variant<int,double,std::string>;
MyVariant list::at(int index)
{
    ...
}
```

For C++14 or below, you can look for `union` (better to wrap it in a class) or use `void*` (not recommended). Or use `boost::variant` for C++11 and C++14.

Comment: yes, i do have vectors of int, string, etc of nodes

Comment: mabe we can do a colab

Comment: What exactly are you trying to create? You can check my project, it creates table where each column can have different types. It can manipulates table data in spreadsheet function style. https://github.com/KSCreator/KMTable

Comment: I cannot use boost cause VS Code and the compiler is telling that boost in not defined

Comment: You will need to install boost libraries, then you will need to tell the compiler where your libraries exists using -I\path\to\boost\headers. It has many header only libraries, so you don't need to link it.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give a solid answer to your question which lacks details. But I still want to suggest a potential solution. Keep in mind that this is only a suggestion.

You might return a `std::tuple` containing 3 `std::optional` values:

```
auto list::at(const int index)
{
    std::tuple< std::optional<int>, std::optional<double>,
                std::optional<std::string> > returnValue;

    for (auto node : VECTOR_OF_INT)
    {
        if (node.getIndex() == index)
        {
            std::get<0>(returnValue) = node.getValue();
            std::get<1>(returnValue) = { };
            std::get<2>(returnValue) = { };
            return returnValue;
        }
    }

    if ( !std::get<0>(returnValue).has_value( ) )
    {
        std::get<0>(returnValue) = { };
    }

    for (auto node : VECTOR_OF_DOUBLE)
    {
        if (node.getIndex() == index)
        {
            std::get<1>(returnValue) = node.getValue();
            std::get<2>(returnValue) = { };
            return returnValue;
        }
    }

    if ( !std::get<1>(returnValue).has_value( ) )
    {
        std::get<1>(returnValue) = { };
    }

    for (auto node : VECTOR_OF_STRING)
    {
        if (node.getIndex() == index)
        {
            std::get<2>(returnValue) = node.getValue();
            return returnValue;
        }
    }

    if ( !std::get<2>(returnValue).has_value( ) )
    {
        std::get<2>(returnValue) = { };
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

But without knowing your circumstances, I can't say if this will be a nice way of doing it or not.

Comment: You do suggest a solution that's suboptimal: The caller needs up to 2 queries to `std::optional::has_value()` to figure out the type returned. Furthermore the lower bound of the required space is the sum of the type sizes instead of the maximum of the type sizes + type info for variant/union+type info. The reason I downvoted though is the fact that your code is simply incorrect: Instead of returning on the first match, you always overwrite the value in the last iteration, even if a match was found in addition to continuing the search for other types even if the desired info was already found.

Comment: @fabian Thanks for mentioning that. I fixed it. Have a look, please.